# Designing a website that will later interact with mobile apps

Tags: iphone, mobile

I have very little technical knowledge and I'm organizing the launch of a new website. Later down the line, we'll launch apps for the iPhone, Android and Blackberry. So I'm wondering if the website should be designed in a certain way to take account of our future plans for mobile apps.

The apps will push information to the website and pull information from the website as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your website with the [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) model in mind, which is basically having website data accessible in the form of web apis, any device that can access web can also fetch data from your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see the http://www.mobilecrunch.com/ and http://www.techcrunch.com/ for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this without more information, but the secret to working with mobile sites is using different css that will customize the site to work with the different browsers.

You should use some type of MasterPage or Template so that as you add additional browsers the css automatically gets updated for each page. And make sure that all your pages are laid out in a manner that will allow css to change all aspects of the page.

This site has some ideas of how to handle mobile site design: http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/mobile-web-design-best-practices/

This link is also helpful http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2005/07/make-your-site-mobile-friendly